# Mostrar "li" salvo no localStorage quando reload na página

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JS, me deparei com o seguinte erro:
Não aparece o elemento novo criado no nó appendChild quando dou reload na página.

```
<ul id="gfg">
<li>Computer Network</li>
<li>Data Structures</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>


function test() {
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.textContent = 'Hi';
    abc = document.getElementById('gfg').appendChild(node);

    //localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('abc', 'abc');
    let a = localStorage.getItem('abc');
    console.log(abc);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

A local storage pode gravar apenas valores em texto. Não é possível vc guardar um elemento inteiro dentro dela e retorna-lo novamente como elemento. Seria interessante você descrever o que você está tentando fazer pra que possamos te ajudar melhor. Interpretando o seu codigo, ele diz o seguinte:

```js
function test() {
    // crie um elemento li e assine para node
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    // defina o texto da li(node) para Hi
    node.textContent = 'Hi';
    // cria uma variavel abc e assine o resultado da tentativa de inserir a 
    // li(node) no elemento de id gfg. nesse momento a ul acima tera uma 
    // <li>Hi</li>
    abc = document.getElementById('gfg').appendChild(node);

    // crie um item com chave abc contendo a string 'abc' na localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('abc', 'abc');
    // pege o item com chave abc de volta da localStorage 
    // (o que retornará 'abc' em string
    let a = localStorage.getItem('abc');
    // mostre o retorno do item abc da local storage 
    console.log(abc); // 'abc'
}
```

Quando vc utiliza aspas simples vc esta dizendo que um valor é uma string. Assim, quando vc faz o codigo abaixo vc esta guardando a string abc dentro da localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('abc', 'abc');
```

Se vc gostaria de gravar o elemento abc na localStorage, vc deveria passa-lo diretamente. Porem como dito a LS grava apenas strings, sendo assim vc receberá um erro ao fazer

```
localStorage.setItem('abc', abc);
```

SUGESTÃO: Guarde na local storage o conteudo da LI e monte ela novamente quando a pagina retornar. Se a LI tiver multiplos parametros, guarde um JSON stringificado. Se vc ainda nao sabe utilizar objetos JSON stringificados, veja a documentação abaixo

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Código de sugestão:

```js
<ul id="gfg">
  <li>Computer Network</li>
  <li>Data Structures</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>

function test() {
  // assinamos que UL sera o elemento #gfg no html
  const ul = document.getElementById('gfg');
  
  // que essa variavel deixe de ser uma li, ela sempre sera li
  const li = document.createElement('li');

  // vemos se existe um item na storage e mandamos ele pra var
  const localStorageLiContent = localStorage.getItem('li-content');

  // verificamos agora se existia algo na storage pra usarmos
  // como conteudo da nossa li e criarmos ela automaticamente

  if (localStorageLiContent) {
    // se localStorageLiContent nao for undefined (vazio) vamos
    // criar uma LI que vai abrigar seu valor (mesmo da LS).
    // criamos uma LI usando const uma vez que nao pretendemos
    li.textContent = localStorageLiContent;
  } else {
    // se nao existia nada na localStorage, avisamos na LI (exemplo)
    // e setamos um item na local storage, assim da proxima vez a pag
    // deve carregar o item da LS e nao cair nesse if
    li.textContent = 'Nada na local storage';
    localStorage.setItem('li-content', 'Conteudo vindo da LS');
  }

  // inserimos a LI na UL (html) seja o conteudo vindo da LS ou nao
  ul.append(li);
}
```